# Custom query_posts() parameter

Tags: php, query-posts, database, wp-query, mysql

I'm adding voting features to a theme. Visitors can vote posts Up or Down. I created a table for storing number of votes for each post and that works fine. Now I'm trying to sort posts by their votes.

I have "voted up" and "voted down" links. For instance, when you click on "voted up" a new  parameter `sort=up` is passed in the URL.

In the loop if the parameter exists and is = "up" I want to loop posts with votes up.

```
wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, FROM $wpdb->votes WHERE up > 5");
```

This is where I want to use something like `query_posts('sort=up')` before the loop. My question is, how to I create the custom "sort" parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data in separate table adding support for it in query is somewhat messy. Basically you will need to filter `posts_where` and `posts_join` to modify raw SQL query so that your custom table is joined and checked against your custom values.

As per [faster :)] anu's suggestion it would make sense to store values in [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and use [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) (related to Orderby, but not same thing) in query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I know I can query anything I need using `$wpdb` but I thought using `query_posts()` would be easier to integrate in any theme since I have to add it just before the loop.

Comment: I didn't mean using `$wpdb` for raw SQL query, I meant using filters to modify internal SQL query that `query_posts()` generates. This is advanced topic so it is hard to come up with definitive example/documentation, see [Custom Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the only way of doing this using the `orderby` parameter is to store the vote values in a custom field.

From the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters)

OrderBy Parameters

- `orderby=meta_value Note: A meta_key=keyname must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical`
- `orderby=meta_value_num - Order by numeric meta value (available with Version 2.8)`

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps I'll store votes in the custom fields table although custom fields aren't ideal for this specific voting feature.